# Collect all xml structs with given name in golang

Tags: xml, xpath, go

Have a problem porting php script to golang.

Is there any method in golang similar to php's:

`$processRefList = $faceContainer->getElementsByTagName('processRef');`

There is an xml file with a huge number of nested elements named `processRef`.

So I need to collect all this elements without dealing with tree of nested structures.

Here an example part of xml:

```
<face>
<processes>
    <process group="1" type="regular"/>
    <process group="2" type="spotUV" state="off"/>
</processes>
<assets>...</assets>
<groups>
    <group id="1">
        <assetRefs>
            <imageRef ref="1" x="0" y="0" id="8">
                <processRefs>
                    <!-- This applies spotUV to this asset and removes the regular process. -->
                    <processRef ref="1" state="off"/>
                    <processRef ref="2" state="on"/>
                </processRefs>
            </imageRef>
            <textRef ref="1" x="161" y="41" id="7"/>
            <textRef ref="2" x="160" y="55" id="6">
                <processRefs>
                    <!-- This applies spotUV to this asset and also leaves regular process applied. -->
                    <processRef ref="2" state="on"/>
                </processRefs>
            </textRef>
        </assetRefs>
    </group>
    <group id="2">...</group>
</groups>
```

Comment: This might help. http://blog.labix.org/2013/06/07/efficient-xpath-for-go

Answer (score -1):

```
////store all xml data in var response
type XMLQuery struct {
Loc string `xml:",chardata"`
}
var l XMLQuery
decoder := xml.NewDecoder(strings.NewReader(string(response))) //store 
all xml data in var response
for {

token, _ := decoder.Token()

if token == nil {
  break
}

switch Element := token.(type) {
case xml.StartElement:
  if Element.Name.Local == "processRef" {
    fmt.Println("Element name is : ", Element.Name.Local)

    err := decoder.DecodeElement(&l, &Element)
    if err != nil {
      fmt.Println(err)
    }

    attrVal :=l.Loc
    fmt.Println("Title: ", attrVal)

}}}
```

Comment: You might want to add some context to your answer!

Answer (score -3):

Try this

```
$extractvar = new DOMDocument();
$extractvar ->load("yourfile");

$itemextract= $extractvar ->getElementsByTagName("faceContainerRefs");

foreach( $itemextract as $value )
{
$var1= $value->getElementsByTagName("faceContainerRef ");
$var= $var1->item(0)->nodeValue;
}
```

Comment: Possibly you don't understand me properly. I try to find golang implementation of php feature. But anyway thanks for answer!